# R: Generating a sequence for a table

Tags: r

I have a table as below and I am generating a sequence for the record_id and Location combination but it doesnt work as required. Notice in the desired output, if the record_id and the location are the same then they should get the same value under my_seq.

```
table<-
record_id   location
1   US
1   NZ
1   AU
1   UK
2   US
2   UK
2   NZ
2   US

table %>%
group_by(record_id, location) %>%
mutate(my_seq = seq_along(record_id))

Desired output
record_id   location    my_seq
1   US  1
1   NZ  2
1   AU  3
1   UK  4
2   US  1
2   UK  2
2   NZ  3
2   US  1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `seq_along()` function just makes a sequence of consecutive integers that's as long as its argument.  Instead, you could use `match(location, unique(location))` which will give you unique values for each location within `record_id` if you first do `group_by(record_id)`.  Here's how it would work:

```r
library(dplyr)
table<- tibble::tribble(
  ~record_id,   ~location,
  1,    "US",
  1,    "NZ",
  1,    "AU",
  1,    "UK",
  2,    "US",
  2,    "UK",
  2,    "NZ",
  2,    "US")
  

table %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  mutate(my_seq = match(location, unique(location)))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   record_id [2]
#>   record_id location my_seq
#>       <dbl> <chr>     <int>
#> 1         1 US            1
#> 2         1 NZ            2
#> 3         1 AU            3
#> 4         1 UK            4
#> 5         2 US            1
#> 6         2 UK            2
#> 7         2 NZ            3
#> 8         2 US            1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>